# How can I store parameters definition in UI extension for Contentful?

Tags: sdk, contentful

I created an UI extension for duplicating an entry with all the childs, everything works but I can’t find anything for storing the CMA access token.
The UI extension is hosted on Contentful, not by me…
I found a lot of docs but for cusotm apps, not for UI extensions.
That’s the output when I’m deploying the Ui extension:
[image]

And on contentful it tells me I have some infos in Content Management API but nothing helps!
[image]
It should be something with sdk.dialogs or sdk.parameters? I really don’t know how to store the CMA token in definition parameters on contentful,It should be something when I'm deploying the UI extension? I really don’t want to use hardcoded values.